# Interface{} type understanding

Tags: go

Can't understand the problem:

```
    var foo interface{}
    foo = make(map[string]int)  
    fmt.Println(foo)  // map[]
```

but

```
    foo["one"] = 1
```

prog.go:10: invalid operation: foo["one"] (index of type interface {})
[process exited with non-zero status]

Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

`foo` is of type `interface{}`. It might contain a map, but it is still an interface.

In order to do a map lookup, you first need to make a type assertion:

```
foo.(map[string]int)["one"] = 1
```

More about type assertion can be found in the [Go specifications](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

> For an expression x of *interface type* and a type T, the primary expression
>   x.(T)
>   asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a *type assertion*.